# Is there a way to turn off file system sandbox prompts for a specific app?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, filesystem, sandbox

I have a Mac App Store app that needs to access various directories outside of the sandbox. To do so, it frequently prompts for permission. I fully trust this app, is there a way to grant it blanket permission so that it stops prompting me?

Comment: I often email the developer and ask to pay for a signed version of the app without sandbox entitlements or restrictions. Most have a set response and it might even fit your budget.